# An attractive introduction to the history of modular forms and its applications

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

I am a graduate student majoring in number theory. Recently I have to give a report to graduate students studying mathematics. I am interested in this field, but I know little about it. Can you give me some advice? Welcome to providing some references! Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty vague. You really don't have any idea what you'd like to say in an introductory talk on a subject that you say are studying?

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea about the attractive part of the report. So the first thing I should do is to find the attractive aspects, such as the application in solving Fermat's last theorem, but I can't understand it well. So I hope you can give me some advice. What book/paper should I refer to?

Comment: The book _Elliptic and Modular Functions from Gauss to Dedekind to Hecke_
by Ranjan Roy might be relevant.

Comment: I wonder why Poincaré's work on Automorphic Functions is not developed in Roy's book

Answer (score 6):

[The 1-2-3 of modular forms](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-03/S0273-0979-09-01256-7/S0273-0979-09-01256-7.pdf), by J. H. Bruinier, G. van der Geer, G. Harder, and D. Zagier (2009)

> An introduction to the roles modular forms have played throughout
>   history, emphasizing both classical and contemporary problems and
>   applications.

Answer (score 2):

"Modular forms, a computational approach", by W.A.Stein (2007) explains many  simple things about modular forms (and how to compute with them) ; it should give you a firm grasp of the basics before diving into "The 1-2-3 of modular forms" by Bruinier, van der Geer, Harder and Zagier (as pointed out by Carlo Beenakker in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

Two other references which you may like and which in particular emphasize the historical aspects:

- ["Elliptic Curves, Function Theory, Geometry , Arithmetic"](http://books.google.com/books?id=CDP1zxFJLucC&dq=elliptic+curves+moll&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by Henry McKean and Victor Moll.
- ["Linear Differential Equations and Group Theory, from Riemann to Poincaré"](http://books.google.com/books?id=txinPHIegGgC&dq=jeremy+grey+linear&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by Jeremy Grey.